# iOS; MKMapView currentUser annotation accuracy circle is bleeding onto parent views

Tags: ios, mkmapview

I've got a map view, as a subview within a semi complex view hierarchy. Everything works fine, except that the accuracy circle, pulsing wave  causes the underlying map view to bleed onto both the navigation bar, and the tab bar whenever the blue, user location pin is near either one. I've got all the parent views' clip subviews set, so wondering what else might be the problem. The view hierarchy is window/scrollview/content/mapview. Thanks.

Update:

I've since tried rearranging the view hierarchy to test various layouts, and confirmed that all the parent views have clipsToBounds = YES and still getting the bleed whenever the "pulse" occurs. Odd things is that the only two views affected by this are the nav bar, and the tab bar. The undesired behavior is that when the pulse ring expands, near either the tab bar or nav bar, the underlying map view begins to draw under the area within those views where the pulse intersects them; as if they are being wiped away and exposing the map view underneath it

Comment: had to give up on this; the work around was doing my own annotation for the current location and not using the built in currentLocation within the map view. I think the original issue may be an edge case bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thought I'd share some recent info on this, in case somebody else happens to hit this same issue.

In my case, I had to set the parent view of the mkmapview (content view) clipsToBounds property NO, and everything worked. It seems counter intuitive, I know, but it's the solution an iOS support engineer proposed. Technically, it's not a supported configuration, but the tech engineer also indicated that it shouldn't bleed like that anyway. I filed a bug for it, as he suggested. The only downside to this is that I had to let go of rounding corners and drop shadow; can't get that without clipsToBounds=YES.